# Whats the best practice for returning a Boolean and string value

Tags: c#

I've created a method that performs some validations against an XML Hierarchy that is dynamically generated by another Class in Javascript text during run time.

My method currently returns either True or False, which is helpful for anyone using my Class but I'd like to also return more informative information since there may be several reasons that can throw a False message.

At first I thought to change the return type from bool to some Generic Collection type having a String key and Boolean value I don't know if this is the best approach.

What is the Best Practice in this case?

Answer (score 40):

Make a class like

```
public class ValidationResponse
{
    public bool Successful { get; set; }
    public string Information { get; set; }
}
```

and return object of ValidationResponse

Comment: dhinesh, I like your recommendation. It looks very clean, extensible and still accomplishes the results I was after. Thanks!

Comment: how would implementing this look like though in a function?

Answer (score 11):

One pattern, which is used in the `TryParse` methods of .NET datatypes (e.g. [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)), and is very common in the C world, is to return a boolean to signify success or failure. The user also has to pass in a value by reference to the method to receive the parsed value back.

For your circumstance, your method signature might look like:

```
bool DoSomething (out string anInformativeMessage)
```

**HOWEVER** I personally think the best approach is to return a `Result` class Dhinesh has  described in his answer, as it's more flexible, and OO in nature. I'm adding this approach for completeness ;)

Comment: I'd prefer an out parameter here, since the message is only written to by the method. Using out also provides a guarantee, that something is assigned to the message parameter.

Comment: @gnafoo You're quite right, and that's exactly how TryParse implements it. Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create your own results class, which your method returns and which contains all the information you need. With this, you can more easily extend it in the future (as in dhinesh's answer.)
2. Another option is to use a `Tuple` object to store both the `string` and `bool`: `Tuple<string, bool>` would be your return type. (Only available in .NET 4.0 onwards)

Comment: Thanks rmx, I have only scratched the surface of 4.0 but good to know about the Tuple object. I will definitely read up on that.

Comment: Tuples have the advantage of being easy to use, but a custom result class provides self-descriptive names for the individual return values. The tuple is probably fine for simple cases, but I'd prefer a real return class or an out parameter.

Comment: Nowadays named tuples would be a nice way to resolve option two.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a Result class as a new return type as suggested in other answers has the problem of breaking existing code.

If you want/need to avoid that, you could introduce a new `string LastError` property containing error messages of the last call to your method, and keep the method signature intact. You'd use it like

```
bool success = myObject.MyMethod();
if(!success)
    Console.Error.WriteLine(myObject.LastError);
```

This approach is not well suited for multi-threading environments.

Comment: In that case I'd probably provide a new extended method as well as the old one. An additional overload (for example with an out parameter) may be suitable as well. The old method can then be re-written to call the new one and throw the additional information away.

Answer (score 2):

The Rust [`std::result` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/index.html) should also work similarly for C#:

```rust
enum Result<T, E> {
   Ok(T),
   Err(E),
}
```

You either:

1. return an `Ok` type with the value
2. or an `Err` type with the error message

---

#### Old answer:

I don't know about best practice but if you only have the two following cases:

1. Return true, with no extra information
2. Return false, with extra information

Then you can simplify it down to just returning a string. If there is no error then you return an empty string which is the equivalent of an error code of zero.

```
string errorMsg = myObject.MyMethod();
if (errorMsg != String.Empty) {
    Console.Error.WriteLine(errorMsg);
}
```

Comment: This is similar to returning a magic number. An empty string doesn't mean success, it just means nobody returned a specific error message, or maybe someone just forgot to set it.

Comment: @EKW yes I see your point. Perhaps not quite so bad as a magic number, but yes, there's nothing to tell success vs lazy. Seeing as no-one here has mentioned the Rust [std::result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/index.html), I've suggested that instead.

Comment: `Result<T>` is a reasonable solution, yeah. Might result in a unusual cases, but is suitable 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

If it is *expected* that the XML Hierarchy will validate - Then I would say this is a typical example of where you should use an exception. The method then just returns void and throws on failure, like so:

```
void validateXMLHierarchy();
```

and to use

```
try
{
  validateXMLHierarchy();
}
catch (XmlValidationException ex)
{
  Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```