# General advice on returning success messages in WCF WebMethods

Tags: wcf

I'm just looking for some general advice with this one please.  My WCF WebMethod needs to work across applications using different software, e.g. ASP.NET --> Java, for example.

I know that in the event of a method failing, I can utilize `FaultException(Of MyError)` to generate a SOAP Fault, however, what is generally the best way to send a **success** message?

Take for example the following interface that defines functionality for saving a user into a database:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub SaveUserIntoDataBase(ByVal u As MyAppUser)

End Interface

<DataContract()>
Public Class MyAppUser

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property FirstName() As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Surname() As String

End Class
```

If I needed to send feedback that the user was saved successfully, how would this be generally done?  Is there a 'success' equivalent of a `FaultException`, or is it recommended to just return Boolean or a String?

I suppose a value should always be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any equivalent success result to exception if execution of service call doesn't fail.

One option is to create some customzed types such as enums and return those based upon different results from underlying source.

The return types of every call may be different or customized to user needs. Returning a boolean value is better than some string value in your case. Also you are using a "Sub", so if its a function then this could be one case.

You can follow some discussion here as well:
[Whats the best practice for returning a Boolean and string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963661/whats-the-best-practice-for-returning-a-boolean-and-string-value)

Comment: Excellent link.  I've updated my feedback in the response below.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a success message. If the operation did not fail, then it was a success.

Use a FaultException to indicate failure.

Comment: Thanks.  Does anything get returned if the operation is successful (even automatically returned by the WCF framework)?  For example, what's to stop the consuming software waiting around indefinitely for some form of feedback?

Comment: A timeout would prevent that. Even in the case of an operation which returns nothing, there's a message that comes back.

Comment: Thinking about it, failure and errors are two completely different things, for example, trying to insert a user that already exists needs to return a failure message rather than a FaultException.  Therefore as per the link provided above, a feedback Class would be best that shows success/failure as boolean plus an explanatory message.  Thanks.

Comment: A FaultException is perfectly fine as a means of saying that the user already exists, if the normal case is that the user does not already exist.

Comment: Great, thanks.  
In your own development patterns, would you normally opt for a FaultException, or do you prefer to add more detail with a return object please?

Comment: If the caller _needs_ the additional information, then place that detail into a `FaultDetail` object and return it with a `FaultException<FaultDetail>`.